# Interpreting infinite integer lattice as a manifold of negative dimension

Tags: manifolds, integer-lattices, dimension-theory-analysis

Various fractal dimensions coincide on self-similar fractals as the logarithm of self-copies the fractal includes divided by the logarithm of the factor by which the copies are smaller than the original.

But if the set includes its own *magnified* copies, the fractal dimension seems to be negative.

Now take the set of integers. It is a self-similar fractal. It includes two its own copies (the even numbers and odd numbers) magnified by a factor of 2. This means the dimension of the set of integers is $\log(2)/\log(1/2)=-1$

Similarly, the dimension of the set of Gaussian integers seems to be $\log(4)/\log(1/2)=-2$.

While various manifolds can be assigned negative dimension this way (for instance, natural numbers are also self-similar), the role of n-sphere of negative dimension would play infinite in all directions equally-spaced  lattice.

This hints us that the "radius" of the lattice is proportional to its lattice step. The set of integers thus is the unit -1-sphere.

Moreover, looking at the formula of the volume of n-sphere

$$V_n(R) = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}}R^n$$

we can see that the volume of unit sphere would be $1/\pi$ while the radius of a spere whose volume is $1$ would be $1/\pi$. This corresponds to a $\pi$-periodic lattice. In other words, a $\pi$-periodic lattice has volume of exactly $1$.

The dependency of the radius and lattice step is as follows: $R=\frac{s}{\pi^2}$

Considering a unit sphere it seems the outer envelope (the surface of the sphere) would be formed by the prime numbers.

I wonder whether this interpretation valid and whether it was suggested before.

Comment: Negative box-counting dimension can happen, see e.g. this related [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196296/fractal-dimension-of-scaling-limits-of-discrete-structures) and refs. within. However the rest here looks strange. The volume of the $n$-sphere is derived for integers $n$ so I don’t see how you can just casually extrapolate it to negative numbers. What does volume even mean for the sets you are considering? This seems to me to be just formula-extrapolation like saying that the sum of the first $-1$ integers is $\frac{(-1)(-1+1)}{2} = 0$ (whatever that means).